# Variable may not have been initialized, does not work when i do initialize

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that outputs the change of a payment in dollars, quarters, dimes, etc. I declare all the coin variables at the beginning of the program, but don't initialize them, and I get this error when I try to initialize them later in the program. So, I just initialized them to 0 to initialize them and then it doesn't recognize that I'm changing the values and they stay at 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChangeClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


        int dollars = 0;
        int quarters = 0;
        int dimes = 0;
        int nickles = 0;
        int pennies = 0;

        double change = 0.0;
        double newChange = 0.0;


        System.out.println("How much was it? ");
        double cost = kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What did you pay with? ");
        double payment = kb.nextDouble();

        if(payment-cost == 0) {
            change = 0.0;
        }

        else { 
            change = payment - cost; //4.73
            newChange = change;

            if((newChange-change != 0 && newChange >= 1)) {
            dollars = (int)(change/1);//dollars = 4
            newChange = (change - dollars);// newchange = .73
            }

            if((newChange -  change) != 0 && newChange >= .25) { 
                quarters = (int)(newChange/.25); //quarters = 2
                newChange = (change - (dollars + (quarters*.25))); //newchange = 4.73 - (4+ (2*.25)) = .23
            }

            if(newChange - change != 0 && newChange >= .10){ 
                dimes = (int)(newChange/.10); //dimes = 2
                newChange = (change -(dollars + (quarters * .25) + (dimes * .10))); //newchange = 4.73 - (4+ (2*.25) + (2*.10)) = .03
            }

            if(newChange - change != 0 && newChange >= .05) {
                nickles = (int)(newChange/.05);
                newChange = (change -(dollars + (quarters * .25) + (dimes * .10) + (nickles * .05))); //newchange is less than .05 so skip
            }
            if(newChange - change != 0 && newChange >= .01) {
                pennies = (int)(newChange/.01); //pennies = 3
                newChange = (change -(dollars + (quarters * .25) + (dimes * .10) + (nickles * .05) + (pennies * .01))); //newchange (4.73 - (4 + (2*.25) + (2 .10) + (3*.03))) = 0
            }

            System.out.println("Dollars: " + dollars);
            System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarters);
            System.out.println("Dimes " + dimes);
            System.out.println("Nickles " + nickles);
            System.out.println("Pennies " + pennies);
            System.out.println("Total change due: " + change);
        }
    }
}
```

I know there are a ton of people who get errors like this and I've looked through all of them to find a solution, but none of them were the same as the problem I'm having.

Comment: Looks like a `Integer Division` problem.  Change your variables to `double` and see if that changes things

Comment: Nope, the value still doesn't change. I'm typecasting so  can keep just the integer part and say there were 4 quarters. Just to clarify why i put that in there.

Comment: try stepping though it with a debugger

Comment: Even after you fix the bug, you may still have a problem because of floating-point precision.  If you get to a point where you think `newChange` is .10, it may actually be something like .09999999 because a `double` value cannot represent the value .10 exactly.  In that case, `newChange >= .10` will be false when you think it should be true.   I suggest you use integers to represent all the values in pennies, and only use `double` for input and output, not for calculation.  Either that, or use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this here:

`  newChange = change;

```
        if((newChange-change != 0 && newChange >= 1)) `
```

if you set newChange to change, then newChange-change will always be 0.
So you all of your if-statements will evaluate to false.

For the precision problem:
An easy solution would be to multiply the inputs with 100 and work with integers. Just think of handling cents instead of Dollars ;-)

Comment: :-D twice the same answer at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this assignment:

```
newChange = change;
```

Followed these comparisons:

```
if ((newChange - change) != 0 && newChange >= .25) 
if (newChange - change != 0 && newChange >= .10) 
etc...
```

You initialize `newChange = change`, so `newChange - change` will always equal zero and all of your `if` blocks will be skipped.

A few more notes:

-Consider using the debug mode of your IDE. You can set a breakpoint and see the values of variables as your program executes each line. Java has fantastic debugging (including remote debugging). Here's how your program looks in my IDE (Eclipse Neon):

[image: debugging in Eclipse Neon]

-A full-featured Java IDE (the big two are Eclipse and IntelliJ, though NetBeans has at least one devotee at my office) leverages many of the features of compile-time type-safety, debugging, and Java conventions. You can rename a variable or method throughout an application with a single operation, you can see whether a method you are trying to call exists, you can even call a method that doesn't exist yet and let the IDE stub it out for you. All these are possible because the IDE is constantly compiling the code in the background as you write it, so it knows every place a class, variable, or method is used. Debugging allowed me to find the error in your code in (I kid you not) 10 seconds. This is why we write Java for enterprise-grade applications!

-Consider using the objects Double and Integer instead of instead of the primitive types double and int, and use the comparison `.equals()`. In the object-oriented world, we prefer to abstract out the implementation of a comparison from the comparison itself. Consider this example:

```
Double first = 3.5;
Double second = 3.5;

boolean equal = (first == second); // false
```

In this example, Java compares the pointers to `first` and `second`, which point to different locations in memory (because each variable has its own space allocated in memory and `first` and `second` are just references to those locations).

This refactor will have the expected behavior in all cases:

```
Double first = 3.5;
Double second = 3.5;

boolean equal = first.equals(second); // true
```

The authors of the Double class have implemented a `.equals()` method that ensures the comparison is of the values, not the references. This is another strength of OO programming; you can `@Override` a default `.equals()` method and implement your own based on whatever criteria you want. This is useful if, for example, you want two class instances to be considered equal based on just one or two of their fields. In your case, using `double` primitives, it's certainly not critical to use `.equals()`, but it is a good habit to get into or you will run into surprises with the `String` class and others.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh my I cant believe i missed that. Thanks a lot though. So, do you recommend an IDE like eclipse over an editor like Sublime text? And also why use those types and the .equals() comparison?

Comment: Edited my answer to include answers to your questions!

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChangeClient {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


        int dollars;
        int quarters;
        int dimes;
        int nickles;
        int pennies;

        double change;
        double newChange;//no need of newChange

        System.out.println("How much was it? ");
        double cost = kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What did you pay with? ");
        double payment = kb.nextDouble();

        if(payment-cost == 0) {
            change = 0.0;
        }

        else { 
            change = payment - cost; //4.73


            if(change >= 1) {
            dollars = (int)(change/1);//dollars = 4
            change = (change - dollars);// change = .73
            System.out.println("Dollars: " + dollars);
            }

            if(change >= .25) { 
                quarters = (int)(change/.25); //quarters = 2
                change = (change - quarters*.25); //change = .73-2*.25 = .23
                System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarters);
            }

            if(change >= .10){ 
                dimes = (int)(change/.10); //dimes = 2
                change = (change -dimes * .10); //change = .23-2*.10 = .03
                System.out.println("Dimes " + dimes);
            }

            if(change >= .05) {
                nickles = (int)(change/.05);
                change = (change -nickles * .05); //change is less than .05 so skip
                System.out.println("Nickles " + nickles);
            }
            if(change >= .01) {
                pennies = (int)(change/.01); //pennies = 3
                change = (int)(change -pennies * .01); //change = .03 - 3*.01 = 0
                System.out.println("Pennies " + pennies);
                System.out.println("Total change due: " + change);
            }






        }
    }
}
```

newChange which you have used is wrong as pointed out by others and you wont even need it. If you go through my corrections, I've used change itself to be used throughout. Hope this helps.